# Text next to image inside a div that changes height based on the height of the image

Tags: html, css

Hopefully the title wasn't too confusing. I'm trying to place an image and text side by side. Both of those are inside a `div` that I want to change the height of based on the height of the image. I've tried multiple things but I haven't been able to do what I want it. Sometimes the image goes below the `div`; sometimes the text is next to the image but with a huge gap between them; and sometimes the text stays below the image, like in the JSFiddle demo at the bottom. Maybe this is something really simple that I'm just not getting. Anyway, here's the code. (After messing with it some much I don't even know what it's supposed to be there or not.)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=500&h=700">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. "</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .info {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-top: 2%;
      padding: 2% 4%;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #808080;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .info .photo {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .info img {
      width: 30%;
    }

    .info desc {
      width: 70%;
      float: left;
    }
```

**JSFiddle Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/dw812685/1/

Thanks!

Comment: You only want the image to affect the parent's height? If the text is longer than the image, you want the text to overflow outside of the parent?

Comment: Yeah, I want both of them to affect it's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your float layout, I would structure it this way.

Float the containers for the left/right sides, and set the image to `max-width: 100%`. Also be sure to use some sort of clearfix on the floated element's parent.

```css
.info {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding: 2% 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #808080;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.info .photo {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
}

.info img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.info .desc {
  width: 69%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=500&h=700">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. "</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use flexbox, set the `flex-basis` of `.photo` and set the text area to `flex-grow` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short)

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding: 2% 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #808080;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.info .photo {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.info img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.info .desc {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=500&h=700">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. "</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a preferred way of doing it or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: @Tiago whatever is easier for you. I prefer using flexbox because I only need to set a width on one thing, then the other one adapts automatically (so less updates). But if you need to support older browsers, you might use floats or some other technique.